# Manejar un event_generate de Tkinter con parámetros

Tags: python, tkinter, eventos

Tengo un aplicativo implementado por medios de varias `class`. Generalmente, cada `class` en un archivo diferente. Manejo de Python con Tkinter.

Bueno, entonces, por ejemplo, tengo la `class` principal `Main` y otra subclase, la `class Salir` que sería un `Toplevel` que se abre a pulsar la opción del Menú de "Archivo >> Salir" de la ventana principal.

La `class Salir(Toplevel)` es una ventana emergente que pide confirmar la salida y cierre del programa con dos botones de <kbd>Aceptar</kbd> y <kbd>Cancelar</kbd>. Además, contiene un `Checkbox` que, si está marcado y se pulsase <kbd>Aceptar</kbd>, antes de cerrarse el programa totalmente, se llamaría a un método de la `class Main` para efectuar una última acción antes de cerrarse.

Dentro de otra subclase de otro archivo que existe en el proyecto, llego a realizar, desde la subclase, una llamada a un método de la clase principal por medio de esto:

```
class Otra_SubClase():

    # ...

    def exec_tarea(self, event=None):
        '''Genera un evento virtual que puede ser capturado
        desde otra parte de la aplicación.'''
        self.event_generate('<<Exec_Tarea_Event>>')
```

Esta llamada la recojo en la `class Main` de esta forma:

```
class Main(Tk):

    # ...

    self.bind('<<Exec_Tarea_Event>>', self.metodo_tarea)
```

y, de ahí, llega a llamarse al método en cuestión.

Bueno, la cuestión es que quisiera hacer algo parecido para el caso del momento en que se pulse el botón <kbd>Aceptar</kbd> o <kbd>Cancelar</kbd> del `Toplevel` antes comentado. Pulsar cualquiera de los dos botones, debería, finalmente, llamar a otro método de la `class Main` de forma parecida a la ya comentada. Pero con la diferencia de que, si se pulsa en <kbd>Cancelar</kbd>, se debe pasar un parámetro con el valor de `True` y si se pulsa <kbd>Aceptar</kbd>, no se pasaría ningún parámetro (o, sino, un `None`).

Entonces, en resumidas cuentas, la pregunta es cómo se podría hacer el mismo tipo de llamada pero pasando, esta vez, un parámetro al mismo tiempo.

He visto un posible ejemplo en un resultado de búsqueda por Internet, pero no estoy seguro del todo de él que, aplicándolo a lo que digo sería algo así:

```
class Salir(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, _w_='', _h_='', _w_='', _h_='', _x_='', _y_='', _tit_app='', *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(_w_, _h_, _x_, _y_))

        # ...

        salir_top_btn_ok = Button(salir_frm_content, text='Aceptar', font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=self.exec_archivo_salir_verif)
        salir_top_btn_ok.grid(row=1, column=1)
        salir_top_btn_cncl = Button(salir_frm_content, text='Cancelar', font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=lambda: self.exec_archivo_salir_verif(True))
        salir_top_btn_cncl.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # ...

        # Y lo referente al Checkbox en cuestión
        # ----------------------------------------------
        self.opc_del_profile = IntVar()
        # Predeterminada
        self.opc_del_profile.set(None)
        self.chk_del_profile = Checkbutton(salir_frm_content, text='Eliminar perfil de usuario al salir.', bg='grey', activebackground='grey', highlightbackground='grey', variable=self.opc_del_profile, onvalue= 1, offvalue=0, font=('Consolas', 7))
        self.chk_del_profile.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

    def exec_archivo_salir_verif(self, cncl_salir=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>', data=cncl_salir)
```

Y, luego, en la `class Main`, sugiere recoger la llamada de esta forma:

```
class Main(Tk):

    # ...

    metodo_verif_salir = self.register(self.archivo_salir_verif)
    self.tk.call('bind', self, '<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>', metodo_verif_salir + '%d')
```

que, si esto funciona, debería llegar la llamada a este método con el siguiente contenido:

```
    def archivo_salir_verif(self, cncl_salir=None):
        '''
        Verificando:
            -> si se canceló la salida:
                -> cerrar otra(s) ventana(s) si estuviera(n) abierta(s).
            -> si se decidió salir:
                -> si se chequeó el eliminar perfil
                antes de cerrar el programa.'''

        if(cncl_salir):
            # Salida cancelada
            self.salir_top.destroy()
            print('Se canceló la salida del programa.')
            # Cerrando otra(s) ventana(s) siempre que exista(n)
            # ---------------------------------------------------
            #   -> ventana de Ayuda >> Acerca de...
            try:
                self.acerca_top.destroy()
            except (NameError, AttributeError):
                pass

        else:
            if(self.salir_top.opc_del_profile):
                # Acción para eliminar el perfil de usuario
                self.prefer_del_profile()

            # Se cierra el programa definitivamente
            self.destroy()
```

Siendo la llamada, desde el menú de "Archivo >> Salir", desde la `class Main` al método que llama a la construcción del `Toplevel` de esta forma:

```
    def archivo_salir(self, event=None):

        # ...

        self.salir_top = Salir(self, salir_top_w, salir_top_h, salir_top_x, salir_top_y, self._tit)

        # ...

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'
```

¿Entonces? ¿Esta forma sería la correcta? ¿Habría otra forma mejor de lograr lo deseado?

¿Recoger el binding dentro de `class Main` podría ser algo del estilo ...?

```
    self.bind('<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>', self.archivo_salir_verif)
```

(pero, sin saber cómo pasar el argumento que llega del método de dentro del Toplevel)

¿en vez de ...?

```
    metodo_verif_salir = self.register(self.archivo_salir_verif)
    self.tk.call('bind', self, '<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>', metodo_verif_salir + '%d')
```

Espero que alguien me ofrezca algo de luz a todo esto que comento. O me pueda ofrecer algún otro ejemplo para lograr lo que pretendo

NOTA: la tecnología empleada fue
Ubuntu - Python 2.7.x - Tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a falta de otra sugerencia mejor, he optado por otro camino con el que consigo lo que quería.

Entonces, en vez de echar mano de lo referente a `self.event_generate('<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>' ...` dentro del `class Salir` y recoger el evento, dentro de `class Main` con las líneas de `self.tk.call('bind', self, '<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>'...`, llamo desde la propia `class Salir` al método deseado de la `class Main`, pasándole o no el parámetro requerido.

Luego, todo se quedaría así

```
class Salir(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, _w_='', _h_='', _w_='', _h_='', _x_='', _y_='', _tit_app='', *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Recogiendo la instancia de la class Main
        # y que permitirá al método deseado desde esta class
        self.parent = parent

        self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(_w_, _h_, _x_, _y_))

        # ...
```

Gracias a recoger el `parent` que es la instancia de la `class Main`, se puede llamar, directamente, al método `archivo_salir_verif()` de esa class desde los botones de <kbd>Aceptar</kbd> y <kbd>Cancelar</kbd>

```
        salir_top_btn_ok = Button(salir_frm_content, text='Aceptar', font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=self.parent.archivo_salir_verif)
        salir_top_btn_ok.grid(row=1, column=1)
        salir_top_btn_cncl = Button(salir_frm_content, text='Cancelar', font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=lambda: self.parent.archivo_salir_verif(True))
        salir_top_btn_cncl.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # ...
```

He corregido el valor, por defecto, del `IntVar()` a 0, pues el `None`, para este caso, me daba ERROR, si el Checkbox no se activaba.

```
        # Y lo referente al Checkbox en cuestión
        # ----------------------------------------------
        self.opc_del_profile = IntVar()
        # Predeterminada
        self.opc_del_profile.set(0)
        self.chk_del_profile = Checkbutton(salir_frm_content, text='Eliminar perfil de usuario al salir.', bg='grey', activebackground='grey', highlightbackground='grey', variable=self.opc_del_profile, onvalue= 1, offvalue=0, font=('Consolas', 7))
        self.chk_del_profile.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
```

El método de `exec_archivo_salir_verif()` ya no es necesario.

En la `class Main`, las líneas de `metodo_verif_salir = ...` y `self.tk.call('bind', self, '<<Exec_Archivo_Salir_Verif>>'...` ya no son necesarias.

```
from Salir import Salir

class Main(Tk):

    # ...

    def archivo_salir(self, event=None):

        # ...

        self.salir_top = Salir(self, salir_top_w, salir_top_h, salir_top_x, salir_top_y, self._tit)

        # ...

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'
```

Y, finalmente, el `archivo_salir_verif()` al que se quería acceder desde la `class Salir`, dónde he corregido la forma de capturar el valor de la variable IntVar ya que estaba mal puesto, faltaba el `.get()`.

```
    def archivo_salir_verif(self, cncl_salir=None):
        '''
        Verificando:
            -> si se canceló la salida:
                -> cerrar otra(s) ventana(s) si estuviera(n) abierta(s).
            -> si se decidió salir:
                -> si se chequeó el eliminar perfil
                antes de cerrar el programa.'''

        if(cncl_salir):
            # Salida cancelada
            self.salir_top.destroy()
            print('Se canceló la salida del programa.')
            # Cerrando otra(s) ventana(s) siempre que exista(n)
            # ---------------------------------------------------
            #   -> ventana de Ayuda >> Acerca de...
            try:
                self.acerca_top.destroy()
            except (NameError, AttributeError):
                pass

        else:
            if(self.salir_top.opc_del_profile.get()):
                # Acción para eliminar el perfil de usuario
                self.prefer_del_profile()

            # Se cierra el programa definitivamente
            self.destroy()
```

Pues nada más, ahí queda para todo al que le pueda servir. A no ser que otra persona pueda o quiera aportar otra idea mejor. Saludos.